# как правильно составить POST запрос для входа в аккаунт

Tags: python-3.x, post

Если кратко то мне нужно войти в свою учётку на replika.ai
я изучил запросы от сайта на сервер и попробовал написать программу

```
import requests
datas = {
  "id_type": "email",
  "id_string": "alina-ai02@alina-ai.ru",
  "password": "12463433",
  "unity_bundle_version": 166
}
url = 'https://my.replika.com/api/mobile/1.4/auth/sign_in/actions/get_auth_type'
s = requests.Session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.post(url, data = datas, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

Но ответ от сервера стабилен

```
{"error_message":"Rejected"}
<Response [400]>
```

я думаю что просто неправильно составлен запрос, но я даже не представляю как его составить правильно(я в этом новичок)

(логин/пароль не подойдут к учётке(немного подредактил))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде, как-то так должно работать:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0',
    'x-device-id': '50843325-B4AA-4D68-A157-A0B6194FDBC1',
    'x-device-type': 'web',
    'x-timestamp-hash': '7cded1779d0bf6aaf91658889baade91',
}

json_data = {
    'id_type': 'email',
    'id_string': 'alina-ai02@alina-ai.ru',
    'password': '12463433',
    'unity_bundle_version': 166,
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://my.replika.com/api/mobile/1.4/auth/sign_in/actions/auth_by_password',
    headers=headers,
    json=json_data,
)
print(response.json())
# {'user_id': '63b8791e6b72e8371c4682e3', 'auth_token': '52591908-336c-4b7d-a8a2-a4f7bb89a820'}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, очень помог